# Creating a web server that responds to every incoming request with a simple message

Tags: c#, .net, webserver

I'd like to create a web server that responds to every incoming request with a simple "Hello" message in C#.

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want a web server or a web service?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since this is a homework question, please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Here is the sample server. http://www.wjunction.com/showthread.php?t=37895

Answer (score 10):

How much of it do you need to do from scratch? It's pretty simple to do this if you're allowed to use [`HttpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx).

Otherwise, you might want to look at [`TcpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) - accept a socket connection, read data from it, and write a response. Admittedly it's somewhat easier if you can answer *every* request with "Hello" as you don't need to really parse it...

Comment: I guess I am allowed to use the HttpListener but how? would u please help me?

Comment: @ghostantanieh: Did you look at the example in the referenced documentation? It's not ideal, but it's at least a starting point...

Answer (score 2):

You can read an article on CodeProject

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/mywebserver.aspx

There is also a project on codeplex

http://webserver.codeplex.com/

You will need Sockets, Multithreading and the RFC http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html

Comment: do you know how can I return a hello message with every request? is it just with write console?